# How to store Abbreviation name in database sql server Through c# programming

Tags: c#, sql

I have Web form, in this web form I have a textbox and a Button. If i insert a data in the textbox as  `"AndhraPradesh"` when I click on the button then it stores `"AP"` in the data base.

Can any one help me what is the code to write in c# so it do as like:

- If I enter AndhraPradesh then it store in the database AP.
- If I enter MadhyaPradesh then it store in the database MP.
- If I enter WestBengal then it store in the database WB.

if statename = "AndhraPradesh" then 
     statename = "AP"
 else if

Answer (score 1):

This will return only the first 2 chars that are in uppercase.

```
string test = "AndraPraDesh";
string abbreviated = new string(test.Where( t => char.IsUpper(t)).Take(2).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(abbreviated);
```

However I am wondering if your rules should consider also the possibilities of two or more result with the same abbreviated string

Comment: Or the possibility that the users won't bother to capitalize things, or will separate them by spaces, etc. I'm not sure what problems OP is trying to solve, but this seems like a fragile solution to me.

Comment: @CharlieKilian absolutely, but unless more context is given, we can only answer literally at the question and wondering what is the real problem.

Comment: Definitely! I wasn't criticizing your answer. I was agreeing with your point about considering different possibilities where things could go wrong, and adding other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RegExp and remove anything thats not a capital:

```
string initials = Regex.Replace("AndhraPradesh", @"[^A-Z]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "AndhraPradesh";
var result = string.Concat(s.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c) ? c.ToString() : ""));
```